# Lyapunov Equation for two optical and two mechanical modes

Tags: python, python-3.x, equation

I am trying to solve lyapunov equation for two opticaL and two mechanical modes, for which i have 8X8 matrix. I defined function for coupling strength G but the code is giving local bound error.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import linalg
import cmath 
import math
def calculate_G(keppa, P, m, omega_L1, v1, t, hbar):
    delta_1 = v1 - delta_rp1 - omega_L1
    G1 = (v1 / L1) * np.sqrt(hbar / (m * omega_m))
    E1 = np.sqrt((2 * P * keppa) / (hbar * omega_L1)) * cmath.exp(complex(delta_1 * t))
    q1s = ((G1 * abs(E1)**2) / omega_L1)
    delta_rp1 = (G1 * q1s)
    alpha_1s = abs((E1 / complex(v1 - (G1 * q1s) - omega_L1)))
    G = (G1 * np.sqrt(2) * (alpha_1s**2))
    return G
omega_m = (2 * np.pi * 30 * 10**6)
gamma_m = 2 * np.pi * 50
t = 0
c = 3 * 10**8
v1=(2 * np.pi * 30 * 10**15)
#L2 = 0.405 * 10**(-3)
L1 = 0.532 * 10**(-3)
#lmda_2 = 1064 * 10**(-9)
keppa = 2*np.pi*250*10**(3)
P = 0.05 * 10**(-3)
hbar = float(1.05 * 10**(-34))
lmda_1 = 810 * 10**(-9)
m = 5*10**(-9)
k = 1.38 * 10**(-23)
n_av = 500
omega_L1 =(2*np.pi* c)/ lmda_1
#omega_L2 =2*np.pi* c / lmda_2
antilog = math.exp((1 / n_av) + 1)
T = (hbar * omega_m) / (k * antilog)
gamma_c = 2 * np.pi*1.6 * 10**6
gamma_a = 2 * np.pi * 1.4 * 10**6
G=calculate_G(keppa, P, m, omega_L1, v1, t, hbar)
print(G)
```

Comment: `delta_rp1` is undefined, so this is not reproducible. Also, your constants for speed of light and Boltzmann are very inaccurate and should be taken from `scipy.constants` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You try to use 'delta_rp1' before you declare it (see your full error message). Unfortunately, this won't fully solve your issue since your variables are inter-dependent. Please double check your equations or implement a numeric iterative solver if you really need to solve the implicit equation.